# Why is liquid plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

I see definition of *liquid* like this:

> a substance that flows freely but is of constant volume, having a consistency like that of water or oil.
>   *"drink plenty of liquids"*

I don’t understand why *liquid* considered plural, while *water* not.

Comment: Because there's more than one kind of liquid.  Tea, water, coffee, soda pop, exercise drinks, electrolyte fluids, etc.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Interesting interpretative. Perhaps it’s just a set phrase, but I’m hesitant to endorse the *types* explanation because the admonition isn’t to drink plenty of *types* of liquids - it’s to drink a large quantity, irrespective of type.

Comment: I think the admonition is to stay hydrated by drinking whatever combination of hydrating beverages you prefer.  This "set phrase" explanation doesn't hold water.

Comment: Do you mean why can *liquid* be used as a count noun to create a plural form *liquids*, whereas words for particular liquids like *water* or *milk* normally cannot?

Comment: I also think the implication is that these liquids are also consumed at distinctly different times.  "Drink plenty of **liquid**," implies a command to continuously drink one long draught of a lot of liquid.  "Drink plenty of **liquids**," is more consistent with a command to drink many discrete glasses of liquid that collectively add up to a lot of total liquid.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have looked at the definition from [the Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/liquid). It's a bit weird (and confusing) in that it gives the plural of liquids in its first example sentence when the headword is singular.

> liquid
>
> NOUN
>
> substance that flows freely but is of constant volume, having a consistency like that of water or oil.
>
> > ‘drink plenty of liquids’
> >
> > ‘First, you should always drink plenty of liquids (water is the best).’

The word **liquids** does include lots of types of "wet stuff", and of these water is but one choice. The inference in the first example is that you drink distinct glasses/cups/bottles over a period of time.

And it is possible to have a plural of ***waters*** but it's fairly specialised!

> The **waters** of a mineral spring can be used medicinally for bathing in or drinking.
>
> > ‘You can take the **waters** at the Pump Room.’

Comment: I agree that maybe it is referred to cups of liquid – in the same manner as light bulb (lights).

Answer (score 0):

The OED defines the noun liquid in terms of the adjective:

> A liquid substance (see A. 1a). In pl[ural] often = liquid food.

What's interesting is that, idiomatically, **liquids** is shorthand for **liquid food** (presumably including water). I don't know of a satisfying answer for why this shorthand came about, but the important thing is that *plenty of liquids* simply means *plenty of liquid food*. Therefore, **liquids** isn't actually plural as used, but a mass noun created from a plural.

Even though **plenty** can modify mass nouns as well as a plural nouns (*plenty of air*, *plenty of noise*), this construction does prime the reader to think of **liquids** as plural. It may help to realize that, although this is a common phrase, it is not itself an idiom, and this sense of **liquids** is commonly used in other contexts; for instance, a sick person might only be able to *consume liquids*.